# mod_cache always stores cached files served over HTTPS with "443" in the file name which causes caching not to work well

Tags: apache, https, cache, port-number

The config file:

```
<IfModule mod_cache.c>
  <IfModule mod_disk_cache.c>
    CacheRoot /var/cache/mod_cache
    CacheEnable disk /
    CacheDirLevels 5
    CacheDirLength 2
    CacheMinFileSize 0
    CacheIgnoreHeaders Set-Cookie
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

A URL for example: `https://example.com/content.png`

In the cache file under `/var/cache/mod_cache` I see `domain.com:443/content.png` instead of `domain.com/content.png`  When I reload the URL, it reload the file version of the image.  If I reload, the URL with the 443 `https://example.com.com:443/content.png` the caching is working fine.

Any idea why mod_cache adds the port 443 to the path of the cached file?  How do I fix this mismatch?